# R Creating a loop

Tags: r, loops, date

I want to create a loop function in which I select a part of a previous variable. 
I have dates which were stored as General in Excel (but I don't know the real origin) in day-month-year but I tried everything to convert it to a date but it doesn't work (01-09-2010 is converted to 0001-09-20).
So I want to make a new variable in which I select parts of the value to create a new one. However I don't have any experience with this so I hope you can help me a bit. I have this:

```
sapply(1:nrow(x$Birth),function(i in x$Birth) sprintf("%4d-%2d-%2d", x$Birth[XXXX], x$Birth[XXXX], x$Birth[XXXX]))
```

But I don't know what to put for the [XXXX] parts. Or would it be easier to use the grep-function?

Thank you a lot in advance!

**Edit**

Sample data:

```
> newdf <- head(df)    
> newdf
       Birth stage vegetables_b_freq
1 01-09-2010     3                 7
2 16-08-2010     3                 7
3 03-09-2010     1                 6
4 21-09-2010     1                 7
5 09-09-2010     1                 6
6 01-10-2010     1                 7

> dput(newdf)
structure(list(Birth = c("01-09-2010", "16-08-2010", "03-09-2010", 
"21-09-2010", "09-09-2010", "01-10-2010"), stage = c(3, 3, 1, 
1, 1, 1), vegetables_b_freq = c(7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7)), .Names = c("Birth", 
"stage", "vegetables_b_freq"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Comment: Not sure, but based on the result you've described, It seems like you have been converting a `%d-%m-%Y` to `%Y-%m-%d`. for you to get an output of `0001-09-20` Can you provide more details on the data frame you've got?

Comment: It is a .xlsx file which I received from a hospital. There are three colums with dates of which two I can easily convert to dates in R using `convertToDate(x$..., origin = "1900-01-01)` however for x$Birth is doesn't work because I get the warning 'NAs introduced by coercion' and all are NA. If I use `as.Date.numeric(x$Birth, "%Y--%m-%d, origin = "1900-01-01)` 01-09-2010 is changed to 0001-09-20.  The class of x$Birth is "character".

Comment: Since `x$Birth` is in character, you need to use `as.Date.character`. For example in the following form - `as.Date.character("01-09-2010","%d-%m-%Y")` will return `[1] "2010-09-01"`

Comment: Thank you! If I try it with one date (like you suggested), it works. However when if I change it to `as.Date.character(x$Birth, "%d-%m-%Y")` they all change to NA.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to help without some sample data, Can you update your question with the results of the following -  create a new data frame using `newdf <-head(df)` and then `dput(newdf)`

Comment: I updated it above.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not able to reproduce the error you've got. `as.Date.character(df$Birth,format = "%d-%m-%Y")` results in 
`[1] "2010-09-01" "2010-08-16" "2010-09-03" "2010-09-21" "2010-09-09" "2010-10-01"`

Comment: I found the error. I used `as.Date.character(x$Birth,"%d-%m-%Y")` but it works when I add `format=` which you wrote in your last comment. Thank you very much for helping me out!